# How to remove sponsored links from github pages' post footer

Tags: jekyll, disqus, github-pages

I have created a blog with `github pages` using `jekyll`.

But below every post there are some sponsored links. How do I remove them.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a link? It could be that the ads are getting injected by software on your computer.

Comment: `http://bhaskey.github.io` I don't think they are getting injected from my computer.

Comment: Hmm, looks like those might be coming from the Disqus widget.

Comment: ok...Can't be they removed?? There should be a way!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys for help.

- Add the site in [disqus](https://disqus.com/admin/signup/?utm_source=New-Site) admin.
- Create `shortname` for the site in **settings**>>General.
- Uncheck the discovery in **settings**>>General.
- Change disqus `short_name` in `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

Those links are part of the [Disqus advertising platform](http://blog.disqus.com/post/82003625662/heads-up-were-testing-a-new-form-of-advertising). Make sure to [turn off the sponsored feature](http://charliesaidthat.com/digital/web-design/how-to-remove-disqus-plugins-new-advertising-from-comment-on-your-website/) from your Disqus account settings.